# Use sed to find extract information and print in specific order

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently having some struggle to figure out a sed command that can extract information and then print it in a specific order. For example,
if I have a text document looking like this:

```
kashd[,]->0123asdj01234/ 
jflskdvnd1234/asdasd[,]->0123asdasd
kashd[,]->0123asdj01234/ 
jflskdvnd1234/asdasd[,]->0123asdasd
kashd[,]->0123asdj01234/ 
jflskdvnd1234/asdasd[,]->0123asdasd
```

then I want to extract the following pars of each line:

```
[,]->0132
```

(any 4 random digits) and

```
0132/
```

So far, I have the command:

```
sed 's/^.*\(\[,\]->[0-9]\{4\}\|[0-9]\{4\}\/\).*\(\[,\]->[0-9]\{4\}\|[0-9]\{4\}\/\).*$/\1      \2/; '
```

This command does extract all matches, but my problem is that I don't know how to change the order because right now it prints the order it's found:

(if command run on the example text above)

```
[,]->0123        1234/
1234/        [,]->0123
[,]->0123        1234/
1234/        [,]->0123
1234/        [,]->0123
```

but I want it to be sorted like this:

```
[,]->0123        1234/
[,]->0123        1234/   
[,]->0123        1234/
[,]->0123        1234/        
[,]->0123        1234/
```

Also, I'm only allowed to use sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't know which pattern will show up first in the line, I think the cleanest way is using the hold space.

Here is how I would do it in sed:

```
$ sed -E 'h;s/.*([[:digit:]]{4}\/).*/\1/;x;s/.*(\[,\]->[[:digit:]]{4}).*/\1/;G;s/\n/\t/' infile
[,]->0123       1234/
[,]->0123       1234/
[,]->0123       1234/
[,]->0123       1234/
[,]->0123       1234/
[,]->0123       1234/
```

Expanded and explained:

```
h                                   # Copy pattern space to hold space
s/.*([[:digit:]]{4}\/).*/\1/        # Remove everything but dddd/ pattern
x                                   # Swap pattern and hold space
s/.*(\[,\]->[[:digit:]]{4}).*/\1/   # Remove everything but [,]->dddd pattern
G                                   # Append hold space to pattern space
s/\n/\t/                            # Replace line break with tab
```

The `-E` option (or `-r` in older GNU sed) allows us to not escape `()` and `{}`. The command would also work without it, but then we'd have to use `\(\)` and `\{\}` instead.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use your command: you can check if a line does not start with `[`, and if so, you can swap the to blocks of non-spaces. If you add this to your command

```
/^\[/!s/^\([^ ]*\)\( *\)\([^ ]*\)$/\3\2\1/
```

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\[,\\]->[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}/' '{ print ($1~/^\[/? $1 OFS $2:$2 OFS $1) }' OFS='\t' file
```

- `-v FPAT='\\[,\\]->[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}/'` - regex pattern defining field value

The output:

```
[,]->0123   1234/
[,]->0123   1234/
[,]->0123   1234/
[,]->0123   1234/
[,]->0123   1234/
[,]->0123   1234/
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hey, thanks but for this assignment i have to use sed otherwise that would have worked :)